# Mesh ontology inference type

Tags: ontology, inference

What is the meaning of the type of ontology inference (materialized vs non-materialized version)? and what bis the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

An ontology is typically stored as and .rdf or .owl file. An ontology contains axioms. Based on these axioms AI reasoners can infer that additional axioms must hold. When these additional axioms are stored as part of the .rdf/.owl it said that the inferences are materialized, otherwise the inferences are non-materialized.